# Надо найти простое число в массиве, никак не могу понять как это сделать. В чём ошибка? C#

Tags: c#

```
    int n;
    Console.WriteLine("Введите размер массива: ");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand.Next(0,100);
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Простые числа: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % arr[i] == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: можете рассказать, что ваш код делает? Я не очень понял назначение того, что вы делаете в приведенном коде.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим в первом цикле вы сгенерировали тестовую выборку данных, а во втором надо по ней пройтись и для каждого сгенерированного числа проверить, является ли оно простым.

Для этого я предлагаю вам воспользоваться методом IsPrime (он не мой, я его честно украл вот из этого вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743192/check-if-number-is-prime-number)

```
public static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if (number <= 1) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

    var boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

    for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; i+=2)
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;        
}
```

и изменить второй цикл, дополнив его указанной проверкой вот так (старый участок кода я закомментировал):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Простые числа: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // if (arr[i] % arr[i] == 0)
        if (IsPrime(arr[i]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь:

```
arr[i] % arr[i] == 0
```

Ты просто берешь остаток от деления каждого число из массива на само себя (результатом всегда будет 0), что к поиску простых чисел не имеет отношения вообще.